# Developer Console script fail with invalid cross reference id

Tags: apex, developer-console, console, developer

I have following code which I am trying to execute in Console but failing with error below.

CODE:

```
Implementation__C I = New Implementation__C();
I =[select Account__c,ID, Name from Implementation__C where ID = 'Record ID'];
I.Account__c = 'Account record ID';
update I;
```

ERROR:

> Line: 4, Column: 1
>   System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0j0V00000NaBYgQAN; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

Comment: Are you using that literal string? Then of course it would fail...you're supposed to replace with a real value.

Comment: No it would be actual record ID. Like this:                         
                                                                                           
Implementation__C I = New Implementation__C();
I =[select Account__c,ID, Name from Implementation__C where ID = 'a0j0V00000NaBYgQAN'];
I.Account__c = '001d000001quQPCAA2';
update I;

Comment: are you pointing to correct org where AccountId exists?

Comment: ID and Console running above code is from same org.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run this code at your console

```
Account acct = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id='Account record ID'];
Implementation__C Impl = [select Account__c,ID, Name from Implementation__C where ID = 'Record ID'];
Impl.Account__c = acct.Id;
update Impl;
```

Comment: Thank you I think it was issue with record. tried both original and suggested code in console is working fine. Thank you Santanu and Andrian for your quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Account Ids all start with the prefix '001' the Id that you have listed in the error message is not an account Id 'a0j0V00000NaBYgQAN'.  Are you sure you are not populating the account__c with the Implementation__c.Id instead of the account?

Comment: The id given in the error is for the record being update not the reference.

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth, no need to query anything to perform an update

```
update new Implementation__c(Id = 'record id', Account__c = 'account id');
```